# SELECT statement that has multiple columns and max value of two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

We track training certificates for over 400 employees using a MS Access database.

Some employees are required to obtain 80-hours of training over a two-year period in which they cannot take a training twice in the same period. Of the trainings that qualify there are company mandatory trainings that sometimes are taken twice in the same period.

As such, these trainings that can be included can only show up once on the query for each period. I am not well versed at all in SQL and did this as a side project for our department.

My goal is to have the query only include one "Privacy Training" for each `DateIntervalID`.

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT
    [Training Extended (Test)].Section, 
    [Training Extended (Test)].[Employee Name], 
    [Training Extended (Test)].[Training Course], 
    [Training Extended (Test)].Hours, 
    [Training Extended (Test)].Category, 
    [Training Extended (Test)].DateIntervalID, 
    [Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date] 
FROM
    [Training Extended (Test)]
WHERE 
    ([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Course] = "Privacy Training") 
    AND ([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date] IN 
        (SELECT MAX([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date]) 
         FROM [Training Extended (Test)] 
         GROUP BY [Training Extended (Test)].[Employee Name], [Training Extended (Test)].DateIntervalID, [Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date]))
GROUP BY 
    [Training Extended (Test)].Section, 
    [Training Extended (Test)].[Employee Name], 
    [Training Extended (Test)].[Training Course], 
    [Training Extended (Test)].Hours, 
    [Training Extended (Test)].Category, 
    [Training Extended (Test)].DateIntervalID, 
    [Training Extended (Test)].TrainingID, 
    [Training Extended (Test)].[Employee ID], 
    [Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date]
HAVING 
    (MAX([Training Extended (Test)].[Training Start Date])) BETWEEN #7/1/2016# AND DATE()
```

This does not get the job done and returns the following for an example:

```
Section Employee Name   Training Course       Hours Category    DateIntervalID  Training Start Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rancho  John Michael    Privacy Training    1   Mandatory Training  3   7/11/21
Rancho  John Michael    Privacy Training    1   Mandatory Training  3   6/15/22
Rancho  John Michael    Privacy Training    1   Mandatory Training  4   11/15/22
Rancho  John Michael    Privacy Training    1   Mandatory Training  4   11/14/23
```

What I need the code to return is the following:

```
Section Employee Name   Training Course Hours   Category    DateIntervalID  Training Start Date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rancho  John Michael    Privacy Training    1   Mandatory Training  3   6/15/22
Rancho  John Michael    Privacy Training    1   Mandatory Training  4   11/14/23
```

Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why have you tagged both SQL Server and MS Access?

Comment: Please include a [mre] with sample data as well as desired results. Ideally as DDL+DML so people can copy and paste out to test.

Comment: Looks like a job for `row_number`

Comment: My apologies Dale K I do not know what you mean.

Comment: When you read the article I linked to, what didn't make sense? You've given us the results you want, but you haven't given us the raw data that would produce those results, so how can we help you write a query? And your favourite search engine will show you that DDL+DML is the create table / insert into table statements to build sample data.

Comment: To be honest as I read the article it appears to me I only included the information/code that is causing the problem.   Which is what i am understanding minimal reproducible exmple to be.   In addition i don't know what DDL+DML is.

Comment: I am willing to do whatever is necessary to get help.  So if i understand you correctly i need to write code (DDL) to recreate my access table that has my raw data.

Comment: DDL = data definition language (how to create the table) and DML = data manipulation language (how to insert the sample data) here is a random example https://dbfiddle.uk/96Bss4Oq  Basically what we need is {[a] a table of sample data and [b] the expected result from that sample data. The "art" is including data that represents all issues to be resolved. NB "sample data" does not need to include any sensitive info and it can even dispense with columns to focus on the "how to solve" rather than trying to get copy/paste ready code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the output to 1 course per employee use a subquery that calculates the max date per employee per course, and then an inner join to the source data utilizing that max date will eliminate earlier incidences of that course.

```
SELECT te.Section, te.[Employee Name], te.[Training Course], te.Hours, te.Category, te.DateIntervalID, te.[Training Start Date]
FROM [Training Extended (Test)] te
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [Employee Name], DateIntervalID, MAX([Training Start Date]) AS MaxStartDate
    FROM [Training Extended (Test)]
    WHERE [Training Course] = "Privacy Training"
    GROUP BY [Employee Name], DateIntervalID
) tm ON te.[Employee Name] = tm.[Employee Name] AND te.DateIntervalID = tm.DateIntervalID AND te.[Training Start Date] = tm.MaxStartDate
WHERE te.[Training Course] = "Privacy Training"
AND te.[Training Start Date] Between #7/1/2016# And Date()
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thank you Dave, Adrian, and those who edited my question.  This worked and I think i understand what it's doing .